# meaning of action flag

Tags: meaning, terminology

What is the meaning of "an action flag" in the sentence below?

> ...your name has an action flag on it, which is directing me to transfer you immediately to the consul general's chief administration.

Thank you,

fate

Comment: It's not a well-known term. It's probably jargon used internally by the organization issuing the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that whoever wrote this, saw some kind of marker on your folder/email conversation that elevate your case to the CG's staff